# Xcode 10 New Build System Clean Issue

Tags: swift, build, cocoapods, xcode10

I recently updated my `Xcode` to 10. As a default, "New Build System" was enabled. When I build my project, I have noticed that my changes won't work on Simulator. When I try to debug this code, Xcode displays the correct changed source code, but the code executed is old.

When I change back to "legacy" build system, everything works fine.

Anybody with similar experience?

Thanks

> This might be an issue with Cocoapods. Because I did unlocked podfile and try to edit some codes.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Changes in Development Pods are not picked up in a new build unless I clean everything. fwiw There is related discussion here (no solution though at time of writing): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoapods/UyxOT5_GFfI

Comment: I have the same issue, this is not only limited to change for pods, when I comment/uncomment one line in my code, the change won't reflect in the new build unless you do a Command+Shift+K. When I switched to 'Legacy Build System' in 'Workspace Settings', it does not have this issue at all. My environment is Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255), macOS MOjave Version 10.14(18A391)

Comment: same issue, except the change which is not being picked up is in a non-pod subproject.  actually: compile-breaking changes are picked up just fine: there's a compilation failure.  but non-breaking changes are ignored. lol!

Comment: The bug is present for so long now and still no solution :/

Comment: still getting this in xcode 10.1

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 10 new build system is made as default. You will face the problem with your project after updating Xcode 10. Apple was aware of these issues and they mentioned this in Xcode 10 release notes.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/build_system_release_notes_for_xcode_10

- When performing `xcodebuild clean` on a project that uses a customized
  build location outside the derived data directory, and that has older
  build products produced prior to Xcode 10, Xcode might report an error
  indicating that it won't delete directories not created by the new
  build system. (40427159)

  **Workaround:** Delete the build folder manually.

---

For reference, here's the full Known Issues section; the clean failure is last:

**Known Issues:**

- Incremental builds may fail to codesign properly for
  non-source related changes to your project, such as resource file
  modifications, which can result in the app failing to launch.
  (41254808)

  **Workaround**: Change a source file within the same target to trigger the
  codesign process, or perform a clean build.
- After installing a Swift toolchain, Xcode won't immediately detect the
  toolchain. (31360319)

  **Workaround:** Close and reopen the workspace.
- The new build system doesn't support On Demand Resources (ODR). If
  your project uses ODR, the legacy build system can be reenabled in
  File > Workspace/Project Settings. (31508570)
- When build settings are defined in an xcconfig file that inherit
  values using $(inherited) or $(), the Build Settings
  editor shows the last assigned value for the setting instead of the
  properly composed value. (28572636)
- Targets which have multiple asset catalogs that aren't in the same
  build phase may produce an error regarding a "duplicate output file".
  (39810274)

  **Workaround**: Ensure that all asset catalogs are processed by the same
  build phase in the target.
- The new "Build with Timing Summary" command doesn't show timings for
  some tasks run within the build system during the build. (39801746)
- Custom build system plugins—including the Intel ICC compiler—are not
  yet supported. (32795438, 33286594)

  **Workaround:** If required, switch to using the legacy build system in
  the File > Project/Workspace Settings sheet.
- Targets with Copy Headers build phases ordered after Compile Sources
  build phases may fail to build and emit a diagnostic regarding build
  cycles. (39880168)

  **Workaround:** Arrange any Copy Headers build phases before Compile
  Sources build phases.
- When performing xcodebuild clean on a project that uses a customized
  build location outside the derived data directory, and that has older
  build products produced prior to Xcode 10, Xcode might report an error
  indicating that it won't delete directories not created by the new
  build system. (40427159)

  **Workaround:** Delete the build folder manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some more extra steps to finally make it to compile successfully. (These extra steps were required even on Xcode 9.)

Xcode: File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System: Legacy Build System

Xcode: Product -> Clean

Rotate to compile thru different emulator types, such as "iPhone 8", "iPhone 8 Plus", etc. (They might fail or might not.)

Follow This step u hope you will resolve issue after follow this step